# NVIDIA vs. 12.04 Unity > Recovery

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, display

I had *successfully* installed `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-302.07.run` from the nVidia website. That got me nothing but an unalterable 640x480 screen. `purge` and `autoremove` didn't seem to undo it.

I attempted, via Ubuntu Software Center, to *reinstall* `nvidia-common`(295.40-0ubuntu1.1), but that doesn't get me anywhere either. `unity --reset` doesn't help (Compiz errs).

Is there anything, short of wipe/reinstall of 12.04, that I could try?

Comment: Open up the additional drivers app and try to disable it.

Comment: Why should purge and autoremove activities from the packages manager work when you installed that driver without the package manager? @bntser No that also involves the package manager.

Answer (score 1):

THIS semi-related "fix" resolved my stuck-in-640x480 problem: [Messed up my 12.04 graphics: Falsely installed NVidia drivers on HD Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156367/messed-up-my-12-04-graphics-falsely-installed-nvidia-drivers-on-hd-graphics) ("apt-get remove" intel, reboot). I'm still scanning the forum seas for a definitively helpful resolution to "Nvidia Can't Do Unity 3D" situation (which lead me to a bunch of Nvidia driver fixes that not only didn't work, but they broke my display).

Comment: So you now installed Intel display drivers while having no Intel card? Are you trying to destroy your installation on purpose? Now would be the best time for reinstalling Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed the driver manually, [you have to follow instructions on how to uninstall the driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual), when installed manually.

For re-installing the proprietary driver from the repositories you probably have to remove and re-install the packages as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131465/cannot-install-nvidia-drivers/133038#133038).