# GeForce 7900 GS Drivers

Tags: 12.04, command-line, drivers, nvidia, graphics

First I had [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2114264&highlight=geforce) problem, I couldn't get the login screen it brought me to tty so I installed other drivers and did `apt-get -f install`
And now I can get to Ubuntu but its very slow and games lag alot right at the menu.
The driver is `nvidia-experimental-304`.
Now I want to install an older driver that will work good.

Can anyone help? Thanks

**Edit:**  When I try to install `nvidia-current-updates` it says this

```
admin@blackhat:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-current-updates : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
                          Recommends: nvidia-settings-updates
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If I understand you right](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2114264&highlight=geforce), you have upgraded the Nvidia driver from the [Xorg-Edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa), is that correct?

> [Warning](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XorgOnTheEdge): This is for testing only! Expect to screw up your X if you try this out.

Did you removed this PPA? If not, you should. You can remove the complete PPA with the following command, e.g. type it on tty1 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> or in a Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. This should downgrade your Nvidia driver to a lower version:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

If ppa-purge is not installed, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge.
```

Also, see: ["Cannot install Nvidia drivers"](https://askubuntu.com/a/133038/23878)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with several Nvidia Cards. Try:

1. Rebooting into safe mode and choosing to repair packages. (Hold shift key during boot)
   OR
2. Using `sudo apt-get update` and then try reinstalling drivers.
   OR
3. Install version 173 with `sudo apt-get intall nvidia-173`

Comment: I tried it but it returns this: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-173 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11`